# Remaining calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

I have a database in MS Office Access, used to manage stock. I have two types of transactions `Addition = when there is a new item`, `removal = when items go out.`

I need to add a section that will return remaining quantity in stock after I add or remove items. What would you suggest?

Note: I have many items, not one item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which DBMS access or sql server and can you add details of exact sample output that is required

Comment: Look for _running sum_. A report can create that with zero code or extras.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'add a section'? Calculate inventory balance when needed. Search topic 'inventory balance'. Could do an aggregate query for stock received and another for stock used then use those queries in another to calculate difference. Or consider:

> SELECT [Transaction Item], Sum(IIf([Transaction Type]="Addition", [Quantity],0)) - Sum(IIf([Transaction Type]="Removal", [Quantity],0)) AS Balance GROUP BY [Transaction Item];

A running balance on form is not practical (not to mention just plain hard to do) especially if records are filtered or sorted. However, you could show the net balance of each item with DSum() domain aggregate function. Try this in the [Inventory Transactions Extended] query.

> Balance: Nz(DSum("Quantity","[Inventory Transactions]","[Transaction Type]=1 AND [Transaction Item]=" & [Transaction Item]),0)-Nz(DSum("Quantity","[Inventory Transactions]","[Transaction Type]=2 AND [Transaction Item]=" & [Transaction Item]),0)

The calc will update as soon as record is committed to table. Record is committed when moving to another record, closing form, or by code to save record.

I NEVER build lookups in tables. I want to see the real values when I view tables.

Don't really need to pull [Inventory Transactions] ID field individually to define sort criteria. This is primary key index and records will sort by this field by default. So pulling in the field with the query * wildcard will produce the same sort.

Comment: Saying add "a section" on my side means to have an additional column that will have remaining quantity after any operation. I have a middle level in SQL, I`m not sure if I use it correctly but did not give me the answer.I have 3 tables -transaction types, Inventory transactions and inventory, I do not know if there is a way I can attach the database that you can take a look.

Comment: You tried the SQL I suggested? If output is not correct then what output do you want? Provide example. I have not seen a way to attach files to questions. To provide files I recommend Box.com fileshare site and post link in your question.

Comment: On Home, new transaction, on the actual quantity. I need the actually quantity to be as remaining in stock. I attach the link: https://app.box.com/s/t060969o5269uxm9tfmfgzpa4xo5esq5

Comment: Thanks for the query, I run it and worked but this provides the remaining quantity without showing the remaining quantity for the last operation. For example 1. add 3 pens, will show me that I have 3 pens, 2. subtract 1 pen the query will show me that I remain with 2 pens. 3. add new 5 pens, the query will show me that I remain with 7 pens what is true. My issue is that: after those 3 transactions when I look to the 1,2 and 3 all will have balance as 7. I really need to have 3 pens on the first low, 2pens on the second low and 7 on the 3rd low. I attach https://app.box.com/file/157596282572

Comment: As already stated, running balance on form not practical. This is best done in report design. However, review https://www.office-forums.com/threads/need-running-balance-in-form.718172/, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2e476a65-3019-47b0-b95e-ea626e9de964/running-balance-in-a-form, and sample database RunningSumInQuery at http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/forum1.html